# using io.socket.get in sails js socket.io

Tags: socket.io, sails.js

I am using sailsjs with socket io. The sails version is 0.10.5. I have following socket client for testing:

```
var socketIOClient = require('socket.io-client');
var sailsIOClient = require('sails.io.js');

// Instantiate the socket client (`io`)
// (for now, you must explicitly pass in the socket.io client when using this library from Node.js)
var io = sailsIOClient(socketIOClient);

// Set some options:
// (you have to specify the host and port of the Sails backend when using this library from Node.js)
io.sails.url = 'http://localhost:1337';
// ...

//Send a GET request to `http://localhost:1337/hello`:
io.socket.get('/join', function serverResponded (body, JWR) {
  // body === JWR.body
  console.log('Sails responded with: ', body);
  console.log('with headers: ', JWR.headers);
  console.log('and with status code: ', JWR.statusCode);

  // When you are finished with `io.socket`, or any other sockets you connect manually,
  // you should make sure and disconnect them, e.g.:
  //io.socket.disconnect();

  // (note that there is no callback argument to the `.disconnect` method)
});


io.socket.on('myroom', function(response){
  console.log(response);
});
```

In my config/routes.js, I have the following:

```
'get /join':'LayoutController.join'
```

In my api/controller/LayoutController, I have the following:

```
module.exports={

    join: function(req, res) {
        console.log('Inside Join');

        sails.sockets.join(req.socket,'myroom');
         res.json({message:'youve subscribed to a room'}); 
      }
    };
```

The problem I am having is that the join function inside the controller never gets fired through socket call io.socket.get('/join',...). The console.log in controller never prints and also no response back to client. If I do the same test through http, it triggers the join function. I am working with socket for the first time. Can anyone please suggest what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Where are you putting the code that you have for your socket client?  Are you running it from a separate Sails or Node server?  It doesn't look like code meant to run in a browser, unless you're using `browserify`...

Comment: Thanks for the reply sgress. I am running the socketclient code separately using node. Eventually, there will be a client. However, this is for my testing. It seems the issue is with my local machine. I got the response for io.socket.get(...) on another server. Another question, not related, does socket.io for sails works with IIS 7.5?

Comment: Socket.io is not maintained by the same developers as Sails, but Googling "socket.io IIS" should give you some insight.  If you can figure out what the issue is with your local machine, I'd suggest changing your title to reflect your system (e.g. "Socket request not working with Windows Server 2012") and then posting an answer so that others with the same problem might find help here!

Answer (score 1):

You can try and run the get request after the socket has established connection with the server as it will act as a virtual request to the sails server over the socket. You can change the code to the following:

```
var socketIOClient = require('socket.io-client');
var sailsIOClient = require('sails.io.js');

var io = sailsIOClient(socketIOClient);

// Set some options:
// (you have to specify the host and port of the Sails backend when using this library from Node.js)
io.sails.url = 'http://localhost:1337';
// ...

//Send a GET request to `http://localhost:1337/hello`:
io.socket.on('connect', function(){
  io.socket.get('/join', function serverResponded (body, JWR) {
    // body === JWR.body
    console.log('Sails responded with: ', body);
    console.log('with headers: ', JWR.headers);
    console.log('and with status code: ', JWR.statusCode);

    // When you are finished with `io.socket`, or any other sockets you connect manually,
    // you should make sure and disconnect them, e.g.:
    //io.socket.disconnect();

    // (note that there is no callback argument to the `.disconnect` method)
  });
});


io.socket.on('myroom', function(response){
  console.log(response);
});
```

This will call the route only after the socket connects. Hope this helps!